# The page cannot be displayed because the client took too long to complete its request and the server closed the connection

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, asmx

I get this error when I try to call my .ASMX Webservice:

`The page cannot be displayed because the client took too long to complete its request and the server closed the connection.`

The Webservice runs okay on my localhost but it throws that error after I uploaded it on the online server!

Comment: Is it possible to display the WSDL of the webservice by adding ```?wsdl``` to the url? May be the server does not process ASMX requests at all.

Comment: no that's not the problem. I think there is some code take too long to run ! I'm checking...